# Keycloak: Map email from Azure AD to auto created Keycloak Users

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-connect

I have added the Microsoft Active Directory as an identity provider as shown below

[image]

and configured the Authentication flow to automatically create the user(s)

[image]

Mapper is configured to Map the user to a Role based on the claims

[image]

Everything works till this part, Users are getting created/added automatically

[image]

However, Email column is empty.

I want to automatically populate the **Email**, so added the required claims in Azure AD as shown below

[image]

and I see the optionally added claims(i.e. preferred_username & upn) in the ID JWToken

[image]

I tried to map the Claim to the user profile/attribute as shown below

[image]

However the **"Email"** column is not getting populated or updated any other attributes

[image]

What should I do to automatically create the user along with his/her Email populated?

Comment: Could you include what **scope** you added while configuring identity provider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `preferred_username` claim is a part of the `profile` scope, do you have it in the list of scopes in your IDP configuration?
e.g.
[Scopes list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSiem.png)

Also, you may use the standard scope `email`, then the claim `email` will be available in Keycloack.